# Azure Data factory expression

Tags: azure-data-factory, etl, common-expression-language

i saw this expression in one of the Pipeine , in the filter activity condition. can anyone help me understad this expresson used( you can refrase inorder to make it understandable). looks difficult to understand.

```
@if(equals(pipeline().parameters.FileName,'default'),endswith(toUpper(item().name),'.PDF'),
and(startswith(item().name,replace(string(pipeline().parameters.Filemane),'*.txt','')),
endswith(toUpper(item().name),'.PGP')))
```

Thanks

I  dont have blocker , but i cannot understand the Expression. Just wanted to get some clarity what is the purpose of that code , what are they trying to achieve in that particualar filter condition in the ADF

Comment: Provide the sample input and expected result and any errors/blockers that you are facing.

Comment: i dont have blocker , but i cannot understand the Expression. Just wanted to get some clarity what is the purpose of that code , what are they trying to achieve in that particualr filter condition in the ADF @RakeshGovindula

Comment: it seems to me that it returns true if the file name is default and the item is a pdf file. or if the item is an pgp file and the filename in the parameters is not a txt file. why? I think we need more information about what this pipeline in ADF is about

Comment: Thank you for the good Explaination @RakeshGovindula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the above expression in the filter activity. It will filter the values of the array based on the `FileName` parameter.

This is my sample array of file names:

```
['rakesh.pdf','correct1.pgp','wrong1.pgp','laddu.pdf','correct2.pgp','wrong2.pgp','virat.pdf','wrong3.pgp','correct3.txt']
```

For you the array will be an array of objects. that's why in the above expression it's there as `item().name`. For me it's only `item()`.

Filter activity filters based on the condition. **If the particular array item satisfies the condition(true/false) then it filters it.**

```
 @if(equals(pipeline().parameters.FileName,'default'),endswith(toUpper(item().name),'.PDF'), and(startswith(item().name,replace(string(pipeline().parameters.Filemane),'*.txt','')), endswith(toUpper(item().name),'.PGP')))
```

In the above expression, If the `FileName` parameter value is `'default'`, it filters the items which are ending with `.PDF`. `if(condition,True case,else case)` so in **true case** we are checking `endswith()` `.PDF` or not. If it is true, then filter condition is true and that particular array value will be filtered.

**else case**

```
and(startswith(item().name,replace(string(pipeline().parameters.Filemane),'*.txt','')), endswith(toUpper(item().name),'.PGP'))
```

If the parameter value is `correct*.txt`(other than default).
In this case it replaces the `'*.txt'` with empty strings('') and returns `'correct'`. Then it checks(**first condition**) the whether the array value starts with `'correct'` and endswith `.PGP`(**second condition**). If both conditions are true, then filter condition is true and array value is filtered.

**This is a sample demo:**

**Array:**

[image]

**Filter with same condition:**

for me it's only `item()` not `item().name`.

[image]

If I take the parameter value as `'default'`.

[image]

**Filter output array (`all .PDF files`):**

[image]

If I take the parameter value as `'correct*.txt'`.

[image]

**Filter output array(`.PGP files starts with 'correct'`):**

[image]

**NOTE:** If your parameter value is only like `'correct.txt'` then use `'.txt'` in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if there is a difference between the first code before '**Thanks**' and the code after it.

But it seems that the code will return true or false.
I can reformulate to this in c# like format:

```java
if(pipeline().parameters.FileName == 'default')
{
    // if the name of item ends with .pdf then return true, else return false
    return endswith(toUpper(item().name),'.PDF'), 
}
else
{
   // replace the *.txt with an empty string. 
   // I think it means if the file ends with .txt then replace it with an empty string
   string replacedText = replace(pipeline().parameters.Filemane,'*.txt','')
   // check if the itemName is ends with .txt (in this case this condition will fail)
   boolean cond1 = startswith(item().name, replacedText)
   
   // if the name of item ends with .PGP then cond2 = true
   boolean cond2 = endswith(toUpper(item().name),'.PGP')
   
   return cond1 && cond2 
}
```